# vis.js timeline, don't stack items with no time overlap

Tags: javascript, vis.js, vis.js-timeline

I'm using vis.js to display a timeline.

I have the following items:

```
var items = new vis.DataSet([
  {id: 1, content: '1) Next To 2', start: '2014-04-20 00:00:00', end : '2014-04-20 00:59:59'},
  {id: 2, content: '2) Next To 1', start: '2014-04-20 01:00:00', end : '2014-04-20 02:59:59'},
  {id: 3, content: 'Underneath   ', start: '2014-04-20 00:00:00', end : '2014-04-20 05:59:59'}
]);
```

id 1 and id 2 start/end do not overlap each other (timewise). So I **always** want them to appear on the same line within the timeline regardless of the zoom level.

However I can't set `stack : false`, as I want `id : 3` to be underneath both 1 and 2.

Here is a JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/uqn6q4jd/17/

1) and 2) should always be on the same line,
3) always underneath

Can I accomplish this anyway?

I have had a look at the Vis JS source, and feel I could probably achieve what I need via alterations to:

```
exports.stack = function...
exports.nostack = function...
```

If there's a setting or feature I am missing that would be the preferred route than me making changes...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I am currently working with vis and have faced a similar problem. If the ranges don't overlap and aren't too small, removing the horizontal item margin should do just fine:

```
var options = {
    margin: {
        item : {
            horizontal : 0
        }
    }
};
```

If you zoom out too far, they will still start stacking, though. A per-group stacking option is [a requested feature](https://github.com/almende/vis/issues/620) and might also do what you want once it gets implemented.

Comment: Use -1 instead of 0 in order to zoom out without the items stacking.

Answer (score 6):

You should (now) be able to achieve this with sub-groups.

When stacking is off, sub-groups can still *effectively* stack (but don't collapse back when you zoom out etc., so they are just "separated into rows" rather than actually managed via the dynamic stacking feature).

You'd need to pre-calculate your subgroups via [an overlap check](https://stackoverflow.com/a/325964/209288), which might get complex depending on your data.

Specifically to your example 1 & 2 would be in subgroup 1 while item 3 in subgroup 2. Subgroup ordering would ensure sg2 was below sg1.

```
var items = new vis.DataSet([
  {id: 1, subgroup:1, content: '1) Next To 2', start: '2014-04-20 00:00:00', end : '2014-04-20 00:59:59'},
  {id: 2, subgroup:1, content: '2) Next To 1', start: '2014-04-20 01:00:00', end : '2014-04-20 02:59:59'},
  {id: 3, subgroup:2, content: 'Underneath   ', start: '2014-04-20 00:00:00', end : '2014-04-20 05:59:59'}
]);
```

Subgroups are [documented here](http://visjs.org/docs/timeline/#items)

Subgroup ordering is [documented here](http://visjs.org/docs/timeline/#groups)

I've just used this approach as a workaround to achieve per-group stacking/or not which is, as @Kazua helpfully points out, still a requested feature.

Answer (score 3):

```
var options = {
    margin: {
        item : {
            horizontal : -1
        }
    }
};
```

i used -1 so you dont have to zoom in to see it stacked

Answer (score 1):

For anyone that runs into this issue in the future.

If the items do not overlap and start at the same time or almost at the same time, I just left the stacking on and set a -25 on the horizontal margin option.

```
margin: {
        item: 0,
        axis: 0,
        item : {
          horizontal : -25
        }
    },
```

This in turn puts all the items on the same line that do not overlap and stacks if items overlap.

I am also using `vis.js - Timeline Version:4.19.1`.